# Run nginx in one container to proxy pass Gitlab in another container

Tags: docker, gitlab

I want to run multiple service such as GItlab, racktables on same host with https enabled in different containers. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this by running a reverse proxy (nginx or apache) that forwards traffic to the different containers using different virtualhosts.

```
gitlab.foo.bar     -> gitlab container
racktables.foo.bar -> racktables container
etc
```

The reverse proxy container will map port 80 and 443 to the host. All the other containers will not need port mapping as all traffic goes through the revers proxy.

I think the quickest way to get this working is to use [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). It's at least extremely newbie friendly as it automates almost everything for you. You can also learn **a lot** by looking at the generated config files in the container. Even getting TLS to work is not that complicated and you get setup with A+ rating from ssllabs by default.

I've used this for my hobby projects for almost a year and it works great (with Let's Encrypt).

You can of course also manually configure everything, but it's a lot of work with so many pitfalls.

The really bad way to do this is to run the reverse proxy on the host and map lots of ports from all the containers to the host. Please don't do that.